# How do I set the IIS 10.0 Management Service SSL Certificate via a Powershell script to allow Web Deploy?

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl-certificate, webdeploy

When I run windows updates and sysprep my Amazon EC2 instance (Windows Server 2016), I have to create a new self-signed certificate. I can then select the SSL certificate (I named it WebDeploy) in the Management Service screen. I have figured out how to create the SSL certificate from Windows Powershell, but I have to select the SSL Certificate from the dropdown in the screenshot. How can I set that SSL certificate from a command line?

[image: IIS Management Service screenshot]

Here's what I tried that did not work - I was able to avoid errors, but none of them allowed the WebDeploy to work without me going into the IIS Manager screen and manually selecting the dropdown.

```
Stop-Service wmsvc
$strGuid = New-Guid
Import-Module WebAdministration
Remove-Item -Path IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!8172
Get-Item -Path  "cert:\localmachine\my\$strHashThumbprint" | New-Item -Path 
IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!8172 
Start-Service wmsvc
```

And also, this didn't work:

```
Stop-Service wmsvc
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8172
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8172 certhash=$strHashThumbprint appid=`{$strGuid`} certstorename="MY" sslctlstorename="MY"
Start-Service wmsvc
```

And finally, this didn't work:

```
Stop-Service wmsvc
Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding -IpPort "0.0.0.0:8172" -CertificateHash $strHash -CertificateStoreName "My" -ApplicationId "{$strGuid}" -NullEncryption $false 
Start-Service wmsvc
```

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the answer at https://forums.iis.net/t/1238001.aspx

I'm not sure if the trusted root store part is needed or not - everything seems to work without that, but I'm very confident the registry keys need to be updated. That was the key to getting this working.

The full script:

```
# Delete any existing certificates
Set-Location -Path "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
Get-ChildItem -Path "cert:\LocalMachine\My" | Remove-Item

#Create the new certificate
$strNewCertficate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -FriendlyName "WebDeploy" -DnsName "yoursite.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -NotAfter $([datetime]::now.AddYears(5))
$strHashThumbprint = $strNewCertficate.Thumbprint

#add it to the trusted root store
$trustedRootStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("root","LocalMachine")
$trustedRootStore.open("ReadWrite");
$trustedRootStore.add($strNewCertficate);

#Use the new certificate
Stop-Service wmsvc
$strGuid = New-Guid
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8172
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8172 certhash=$strHashThumbprint appid=`{$strGuid`} certstorename="MY"

#convert thumbprint to bytes and update registry
$bytes = for($i = 0; $i -lt $strHashThumbprint.Length; $i += 2) { [convert]::ToByte($strHashThumbprint.SubString($i, 2), 16) }
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server' -Name IPAddress -Value "*";
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server' -Name SslCertificateHash -Value $bytes
Start-Service wmsvc
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS version notwithstanding, this question appears to be very similar to...

[How to assign an different SSL certificate for the IIS7+ Management Service on Server-Core?](https://serverfault.com/questions/385180/how-to-assign-an-different-ssl-certificate-for-the-iis7-management-service-on-s)

```
# get the thumbprint for the certificate we want to use:
$thumb = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\MY | where-object { $_.FriendlyName -eq   "www.stackoverflow.com" } | Select-Object -First 1).Thumbprint
# get a new guid:
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid()

# remove the self-signed certificate:
& netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8172
# add the 'proper' certificate:
& netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8172 certhash=$thumb appid=`{$guid`}
```

Comment: If you look at the things I tried that did not work, this is the second one. I tried different variations of this. The commands worked, but it did not set the dropdown, and also did not allow me to validate the connection or publish. And, the dropdown remains blank after running.

Comment: To be clearer, after running the netsh http delete and netsh http add commands, which work without error, I cannot restart wmsvc. The event log is not very helpful: The Web Management Service service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Unspecified error